# How to set new key-values in useState and then update them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useState set as:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState([{}])
```

I am using a useState for an onChange where the data is returning:

```
[
   {id: 'abc', statuses: ['created', 'finished'],
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['created', 'started', 'finished']
]
```

The items in the statuses array can change with the onChange (e.g., statuses: ['created', 'finished'] can become statuses: ['created', 'in progress', 'finished']).
I am wondering how I can initially set a key-value pair for each dictionary if the id does not already exist in the useState or update the statuses key-value pair if the id does exist.

I have tried to initialize the useState, but I get an error of "expected 1 argument, but got 2" and I am not sure if I did the spread operator correctly:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setTransitionKeys(prev => [...prev], {id: newData.id, statuses: newData.statuses})
```

I have tried to update the useState with:

```
setStatus(
   status.map((value, index) => {
      if (value.id === onChangeData.id){
         return {
            ...value, statuses: onChangeData.statuses
         }
      }
   }
)
```

If there is a better way to solve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you state is

```
state = [
   {id: 'abc', statuses: ['created', 'finished'],
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['created', 'started', 'finished']
]
```

And you need to do it like

```
[
   {id: 'abc', statuses: ['created', 'finished'],
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['created', 'started', 'finished'],
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['created', 'started', 'finished']
]
```

Than you can do

```
setState([...state, {id: 'def', statuses: ['created', 'started', 'finished']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when setting the status, the new value will need to do one of the following:

1. Not existing in the array > add to the status array
2. Existing in the array > update (replace) the value in the status array

When setting the state:

```
  setStatus((prev) => {

    // Get a new array from prev stat that excludes item with same id
    // If no value matches the id, it will be same as prev array

    const prevFiltered = prev.filter((value) => value.id !== onChangeData.id);

    // return the filtered array with new value
    // since the filter eliminated any duplicate value,
    // this will cover the case of adding and updating

    return [...prevFiltered, onChangeData];
  });
```

Just added a full example, hopefully will help make it clear:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState([
    { id: "abc", statuses: ["created", "finished"] },
    { id: "def", statuses: ["created", "started", "finished"] },
  ]);


// can play around with these values to simulate different situations
  const addingData = { id: "ghi", statuses: ["created", "finished"] };
  const updatingData = {
    id: "abc",
    statuses: ["created", "started", "finished"],
  };

  const handleChange = (newData) => {
    setStatus((prev) => {
      const prevFiltered = prev.filter((value) => value.id !== newData.id);
      return [...prevFiltered, newData];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* simulate add some data (not existing id) */}
      <button onClick={() => handleChange(addingData)}>ADD</button>

      {/* simulate update some data (existing id) */}
      <button onClick={() => handleChange(updatingData)}>UPDATE</button>

      {/* log the current status */}
      <button onClick={() => console.log(status)}>LOG</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If still unclear, perhaps posting the actual use case would help, as it helps understand how stats should change.

Comment: For this, it says "property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'" on the prev.filter((value) => value.id part. 
Should I initialize my useState with a blank id (e.g., useState([{id: ''}]) ?)

Comment: Initialize with empty array is okay, or with actual default values, but not array of empty object.

Comment: Hi, sorry I have another question. For initializing the useState with the useEffect, it keeps rewriting the prev data with the most recent data. For example, the useState is [ {id: 'abc', status: ['...']}]. When a new data is created it becomes [ {id: 'def', status: ['...']}), so the initial abc id is erased. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Just added a full example hopefully will help make it clear, but I did not use `useEffect` here so perhaps post your changed code?  So it can be checked where went wrong

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple project with your requirement, and the logics are at
`handleToAddOrUpdateStatus` function.

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const inputIdRef = useRef();
  const inputStatusRef = useRef();

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: "abc", statuses: ["created", "finished"] },
    { id: "def", statuses: ["created", "started", "finished"] }
  ]);

  const handleToAddOrUpdateStatus = () => {
    setData((prev) => {
      // get the enter values from "Id" input and "Add status" input
      const idValue = inputIdRef.current.value;
      const statusValue = inputStatusRef.current.value;

      // Check: does the id exist? True has exist | False hasn't exist
      const hasId = prev.some((status) => status.id === idValue);

      // If id exists => Update statuses property for the object duplicates id
      if (hasId) {
        const newData = [...prev].map((item) => {
          if (
            item.id === idValue &&
            item.statuses.every((element) => element !== statusValue)
          )
            return { ...item, statuses: [...item.statuses, statusValue] };
          return item;
        });
        return newData;
      }

      // If  id doesn't exist, add the new object.
      return [...prev, { id: idValue, statuses: [statusValue] }];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label id="id">ID: </label>
      <input type="text" id="id" ref={inputIdRef} />
      <br />
      <label id="status">Add Status: </label>
      <input type="text" id="status" ref={inputStatusRef} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleToAddOrUpdateStatus}>Add or Update data</button>

      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{`${item.id}: ${item.statuses.join(", ")} `}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

You can demo it at this like: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-architecture-0kcmit?file=/src/App.js:327-998